# Manga where the main character reincarnates and trains so intently that their child's body is overly muscular

Tags: story-identification, manga

The person reincarnates I think into a noble of some sorts and he begins to train his body very intensely, to the point he is so muscular even his dad had a thought bubble that said 'there's not the body a child of his age should have...'

He was also an adventurer and one of his belongings was in a treasure room held by a family to help many historical Treasures. One of his old thing was in it and they didn't know what the hell it was. They told him he could have that and shoot something else I believe he got like a wind sword and summoned the god of wind through the sword talk to it about the past life.

He also fights his other brother who acts arrogantly, challenging to fight and gets demolished instantly.

The manga is similar to: *Jitsu wa Ore, Saikyou deshita? ~ Tensei Chokugo wa Donzoko Sutāto* and *Demo Ban’nō Mahō de Gyakuten Jinsei o Jōshō-chū!*...

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.